# Angular with multiples $anchorScroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular `$anchorScroll` and it is working perfect, the only problem is: i will have 100 links in the page, so what is the best way to make my angular code clean? without create a function for every anchor link?

html:

```
    <div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
      <a ng-click="gotoBottom()">Go to bottom</a>
      <a id="bottom"></a> bottom!
    </div>

  <div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
      <a ng-click="gotoHeader()">Go to header</a>
      <a id="header"></a> header!
    </div>

 <div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
      <a ng-click="gotoMid()">Go to mid</a>
      <a id="mid"></a> mid!
    </div>
```

script.js

```
    angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
    .controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
      function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
        $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
          $location.hash('bottom');
          $anchorScroll();
        };
     $scope.gotoMid = function() {
      $location.hash('mid');
      $anchorScroll();
     };

     $scope.gotoHeader= function() {
      $location.hash('header');
      $anchorScroll();
     };

    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameter to function invoked in template.

```
 angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
 .controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
      function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
          $scope.goto = function(anchor){
              $location.hash(anchor);
              $anchorScroll();
         }
}]);
```

Then in view:

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">
  <a ng-click="goto('header')">Go to header</a>
  <a id="header"></a> header!
</div>
```

Comment: There was syntax error in first snippet. Was it this ?

Comment: You have to start angular. For example wrap your html with additional `div` with attribute `ng-app="anchorScrollExample"`. Then it should start working.